# Angular 2 are nested routes components children of the parent route component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Are nested routes components children of the parent route component? i.e. am I able to communicate using an Output from a child route component to the parent route component? If not what would the recommended strategy be? As if the components when routing don't have a parent\child relationship then they wouldn't be sharing the same service singleton object either?

Answer (score 1):

A good solution is to use the service to communicate between components/routes.

Services are the same throughout the application, read about:

[Angular2 - Component Interaction (Communication via a service)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service)

[Angular2 - Dependency injection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html)